# Create multiple instances of the same function with different variables each time in a Socket.io event

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I need to create multiple instances of the same function with different variables passed from the front end in a socket.io event.  I also need these variables visible to another socket.io event so that I can stop the function from a front end click.  I have everything working great, but I can only use it for one instance with a set variable 'bigLoop' and need it to work for multiple instances. I need all of the loops to be able to run and independent of each other.

The socket event:

```js
    //this is what I have so far and it works great, I can start and stop at any time. And I know bigLoop is global
    io.on('connection', function(connect) {
        //create new loop
       connect.on('createLoop', function(data) {
           bigLoop = new syncLoop(data.total, function(){}, function(){});
       });
        //end loop
       connect.on('endLoop', function(data) {
           bigLoop.break(true);
       });
    });



  //this is what I would like passing an array of multiple variables from the front end and creating a new syncLoop for each variable
        //create new loop
        connect.on('createLoop', function(data) {
           //save array to variable
           var newNames = data.array;
           //for each variable create new syncLoop
           newNames.forEach(function(newLoops) {
               newloops = new syncLoop(data.total, function(){}, function()  {});
           });
        });
           
        //end loop
       connect.on('endLoop', function(data) {
           //save array to variable
           var endNames = data.array;
           //for each variable end loop
           endNames.forEach(function(endLoops){
               endLoops.break(true);
           });
          
       });




//syncLoop function, for process and exit I have a lot more going on but did not want to write it
function syncLoop(iterations, process, exit){  
 var index = 0,
     done = false,
     shouldExit = false;

    loop = {
        next:function(){
            if(done){
                if(shouldExit && exit){
                    return exit(); // Exit if we're done
                }
            }
            // If we're not finished
            if(index < iterations){
                index++; // Increment our index
                process(loop); // Run our process, pass in the loop
            // Otherwise we're done
            } else {
                done = true; // Make sure we say we're done
                if(exit) exit(); // Call the callback on exit
            }
        },
        iteration:function(){
            return index - 1; // Return the loop number we're on
        },
        break:function(end){
            done = true; // End the loop
            shouldExit = end; // Passing end as true means we still call the exit callback
        }
    };
    loop.next();
    return loop;
};
```

I have tried a lot of different things and I cannot get this to work.  I appreciate any help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly:

Try creating a global map of all the running loops:

```
// global variable
var loops = {};

function createLoop(name, data) {
  stopLoop(name);
  loops[name] = new syncloop(/*...*/);
}

function stopLoop(name) {
  if (loops[name]) {
    loops[name].break(true);
    delete loops[name]; // remove entry from map
  }
}
```

The variable `loops` would contain all of the currently-running loops, by name.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! I just adjusted the code, and it is starting and stopping loops and multiple loops.

Comment: I did, but I do not have a reputation of 15 yet.  It is recorded but not publicly displayed. I will try and up my reputation and come back and click again. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, ok. Glad I could help.